# Can you export/capture the contents of a Genius Mix?

Tags: itunes

In iTunes, I know you can save a Genius *Playlist*, and you can see a few songs ahead in a Genius *Mix* by looking at `Up Next`, but is there any way to actually save a Genius-Mix-generated playlist?

Or is it that the Genius Mix playlist doesn't even exist (more than the few songs in `Up Next`)?  Like, is iTunes just popping another random song (of the appropriate category) on the end of the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so with [this AppleScript](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/scripts/ss.php?sp=dumbdowngeniusmix).

Answer (score 1):

This script will copy the tracks of a playing Genius Mix playlist to a new "dumb" (regular) playlist, which, for example, can be copied/sync'd to older iPods that do not accommodate Genius Mixes. You can subsequently copy the contents of additional Genius Mix playlists to the new playlist, refill it, or create more. (Each Genius Mix playlist only contains about 70 tracks maximum, which is why you may have several, say, "Rock Mix" playlists.)

Doug's Script:  http://dougscripts.com/itunes/scripts/ss.php?sp=dumbdowngeniusmix

Comment: Isn't that the same script as [Kirk McElhearn's answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/80697/10389)?